# Expand Pandas Group By to Many Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like this,

create a data frame `data`

```
d = {'Machine ID': [100, 100, 101, 101], 'Machine': ["ABC", "ABC", "CDQ", "CDQ"], 
    "June": [10,0,12,15], "July": [12,15,0,32], "August": [0,15,20,11]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Data Frame:

```
 Machine ID Machine June    July    August
0   100     ABC      10     12     0
1   100     ABC      0      15     15
2   101     CDQ      12     0      20
3   101     CDQ      15     32     11
```

Now, I want to `groupby` and aggregate by month, so, I did this,

```
machine_group = data.groupby(['Machine ID','Machine'])['June'].sum().reset_index(name = 'June Sum')
```

I get the following,

```
 Machine ID Machine June Sum
0   100     ABC     10
1   101     CDQ     27
```

However, I need an ouput something like this

```
         Machine ID Machine June Sum July Sum August Sum
    0   100     ABC         10       27       15
    1   101     CDQ         27       32       31
```

How can I expand my group by code to get them lines up. Otherwise, for now, my option is to group by each month and append grouped column into a new data frame. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You are grouping, and then performing `.sum` only on one of the series (by slicing with `['June']`). You can apply it to all of the series but just doing `.sum()` after the groupby. If you need to perform different operations on different columns, then you should look into [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
machine_group = data.groupby(['Machine ID','Machine']).sum()\
                    .add_suffix(' Sum').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Machine ID Machine  June Sum  July Sum  August Sum
0         100     ABC        10        27          15
1         101     CDQ        27        32          31
```

Comment: .add_prefix('Sum ')

Comment: @Scott Boston, what did I miss? this looks almost similar to my code

Comment: @user9431057 You need didn't need to add the aggregating columns, let it just aggregate all numeric columns in the dataframe not included in the groups.

Comment: @user9431057 And, we used `add_suffix` to supplement the columns header with ' Sum' a quick way of renaming.